# Lower volume of subwoofer

Tags: speakers

I have a 5.1 dvd player. The volume of subwoofer is high even after setting low in remote. Is it possible to lower volume by adding resistor between dvd player and woofer output line. If so how much resistance is needed. I want to lower volume to half

Subwoofer ( 95w 3ohm)
Amplifier (dvd player) (95w 3ohm)

It's a 5.1 dvd player samsung hte330k
It has 6 output ports for four speakers and 1 woofer

the specs are here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DLPC.png)

Comment: There should be a subwoofer volume adjustment on the actual subwoofer.

Comment: there is no adjustment knob\

Comment: Please add the model and/or part numbers of the components involved.

Comment: It's a 5.1 dvd player samsung hte330k
It has 6 output ports for four speakers and 1 woofer

Answer (score 1):

From Samsung:
Most soundbar remotes have a button labeled WOOFER that can adjust the level from -6 to +6 (when compared with the volume of the rest of the sound from the other speakers). If your remote does not have this button, see your user manual for instructions.

Additionally, can you trim the other speakers up?
Also, the acoustic effects of placing a sub in a corner or enclosed area increase frequency buildup via standing waves(think singing in the shower).  If it's placed in a corner, move it out a foot/.3ish meters away from the wall/adjacent hard surface.
If it is downfiring(speaker on the bottom), you can flip it over...
Just trying to rule out environmental issues first.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an unpowered subwoofer, ie no internal driver and hence no internal volume control, you have a few options.

An L-pad is a pair of resistors (pots) used to attenuate a speaker without built in control. You need one that can handle 95W and your subwoofer resistance (3 ohm). Or you can make your own to make it a fix attenuation. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/attenuators/l-pad-attenuator.html has all the math needed. Individual parts may be more expensive than a commercial l-pad.

Alternatively you can hack the dvd players hardware. There is undoubtedly a analog audio power amp circuit on the board. By figuring out the IC and passive components you could rewire it to have a lower amplification or power output. You could hack the firmware but that's a long shot.

Finally you could move or cover the subwoofer. Just move it back, turn it around, face the wall or curtains or cover it with a sheet or rug or something. This would change the perceived sound levels.